# Generate a pyramid in R using a vector and a defined scalar

Tags: r

Let's say we have a vector of all letters:

```
#Vector
Vec <- LETTERS
```

Then, we define a constant like `n`:

```
#Constant
n <- 10
```

How can I sketch a code so that I can start first line with one element and so on until the last line where it has the first `n` elements in `Vec`?

In some manner this is like a pyramid and even first line only has 1 element, it should have `n-1` spaces to fit with the rest of rows.

Expected output would be:

```
#A
#AB
#ABC
#ABCD
#ABCDE
#ABCDEF
#ABCDEFG
#ABCDEFGH
#ABCDEFGHI
#ABCDEFGHIJ
```

Take into account that `n` can be larger and if `n` is greater than the size of `Vec` then the initial element should complete the row like `XYZABC`.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a function that prints the expected results:

```
M<-function(vec, n){
  d <- length(vec)
  m <- sapply(seq_len(n) - 1, function(x)
    paste(Vec[seq(0, x) %%d + 1], collapse = ""))
  cat(m, sep="\n")
}

M(Vec, 10)
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
ABCDEF
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHI
ABCDEFGHIJ

M(Vec[1:3], 10)
A
AB
ABC
ABCA
ABCAB
ABCABC
ABCABCA
ABCABCAB
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABCA
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `substring` with `cat` after creating single string from 'Vec'

```
cat(paste(substring(paste(Vec, collapse=""), 1, seq_len(n)), collapse="\n"), "\n")
```

-output

```
#A
#AB
#ABC
#ABCD
#ABCDE
#ABCDEF
#ABCDEFG
#ABCDEFGH
#ABCDEFGHI
#ABCDEFGHIJ
```

Or as @Onyambu suggested with a compact option

```
cat(substring(paste(Vec, collapse=""), 1, seq_len(n)),sep= "\n")
```

Comment: why do you need the second `paste`? You could directly do `cat(substring(paste(Vec, collapse=""), 1, seq_len(n)),sep= "\n")` . Great solution:

Answer (score 2):

@akrun's answer and @Onyambu's suggestion are pretty concisely put.

The OP asked for it to loop back to the beginning of the vector if it exceeded the length though, so we do need an additional bit of code to repeat the vector.

```
vec = LETTERS

n = 30

# Repeats string as many times as needed
temp_vec <- rep(vec,ceiling(n/length(vec)))
  
#Creates "pyramid"
cat(substring(paste(temp_vec, collapse=""), 1, seq_len(n)),sep= "\n")
```

Of course, you can put this all in one line, but, personally,

```
cat(substring(paste(rep(vec,ceiling(n/length(vec))), collapse=""), 1, seq_len(n)),sep= "\n")
```

is just a little too long for my taste.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
cat(paste0(sapply(seq(n), function(k) paste0(Vec[(seq(k) - 1) %% length(Vec) + 1], collapse = "")), collapse = "\n"))
```

which gives

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
ABCDEF
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHI
ABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJKL
ABCDEFGHIJKLM
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
```

if given `n <- 29`